# Difficult problem with running an executable in Elementary

Tags: plank

Using 0.3.1 Freya, 64-bit.

Here's my problem.  I have an app, Isoplex, a clone of Popcorn-Time, that runs as an executable.  I have it stored in my /home/jeff/ directory.

Double-clicking on the file in Files does nothing, although I have it marked as executable.  But navigating to the directory, and then invoking "./Isoplex", runs it just fine.

I've tried dragging the executable to Plank, but it won't launch from there, either.

I get a ton of stuff when I run from terminal.  I'll paste the output here -- I can't make heads or tails of what's happening here.  And note that, after all this scrolls, the app finally runs.

Can someone help me so that I can launch Isoplex from Plank?  Thanks.

```
eff@jeff-All-Series:~/Isoplex$ ./Isoplex
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(170)] Running without the SUID sandbox! See https://code.google.com/p/chromium/wiki/LinuxSUIDSandboxDevelopment for more information on developing with the sandbox on.
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "pantheon-filechooser-module"
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(198)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(198)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(198)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(198)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
[2667:1008/232140:ERROR:browser_main_loop.cc(198)] GTK theme error: Unable to locate theme engine in module_path: "pixmap",
Gtk-Message: Failed to load module "canberra-gtk-module"
ATTENTION: default value of option force_s3tc_enable overridden by environment.
[2667:1008/232143:INFO:CONSOLE(13)] ""Database path: /home/jeff/.config/Isoplex"", source: app://host/src/app/database.js (13)
[2667:1008/232143:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Scanning: Local Network for Airplay devices" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232143:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Scanning: Local Network for DLNA devices" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232143:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Scanning: /usr/bin" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232143:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Scanning: /usr/local/bin" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Spawning new provider" "color: blue;" "color: black;" "TVApi"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Loading DB" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(28)] ""track done"", source: app://host/src/app/bootstrap.js (28)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Initializing HTTP API server" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %cChecking %s endpoint" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;" "eztvapi.re"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %cChecking %s endpoint" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;" "popcorntime.io"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
[2667:1008/232144:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] External Players: scan finished" "color: blue;" "color: black;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Spawning new provider" "color: blue;" "color: black;" "Trakttv"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Spawning new provider" "color: blue;" "color: black;" "TVShowTime"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %cAutomatic updating disabled" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Spawning new provider" "color: blue;" "color: black;" "Yts"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(43)] ""[%cINFO%c] Spawning new provider" "color: blue;" "color: black;" "YSubs"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (43)
[2667:1008/232145:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %cPopcorn Time %s startup time: %sms" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;" "0.3.8-0" "1979.828"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
[2667:1008/232146:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %c49 cached subtitle" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
[2667:1008/232146:INFO:CONSOLE(38)] ""%c[%cDEBUG%c] %cCache 0 subtitle" "color: black;" "color: green;" "color: black;" "color: blue;"", source: app://host/src/app/app.js (38)
```

Answer (score 1):

To run any executable from plank you will need to create a `.desktop` file. To create one open your preferred text editor as root and create a the file `/usr/share/applications/lsoplex.desktop` with the content

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=Lsoplex
Comment=Anything you like
Exec=the path to the executable
Path=the folder to executable is i
Icon=Any svg icon
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to go to the executable file, right click on it and open properties.
Then choose the second tab and check if you have execute permissions. Also make sure that you are the owner of the file (and not the root user).

Now try to open it. Does it work? If not, right click again and then press run.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a `Launcher` first (.desktop file). You can create that manually or use [MenuLibre](https://bluesabre.org/projects/menulibre/) for that.

Since your command is in your home directory, your command needs the whole path: `/home/youruser/Isoplex`

Once created you can now drag that `Launcher` to your Plank.

[image: MenuLibre Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [smdavis.us](https://smdavis.us/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/menulibre_2014_07.png))</sub>